# Jpages Plugin not worked properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have implemented Jpages Plugin from [here](http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/defaults.html). I have used following code..

```
$(function () {
               $("div.holder").jPages({
                   containerID: "movies",
                   previous: "←",
                   next: "→",
                   perPage: 10,
                    startPage    : 1,
                    startRange   : 1,
                    midRange     : 5,
                    endRange: 1,
                    keyBrowse: true,
                   delay: 50
               });
           });
```

My perpage size is currently set 10 and my current record count is 6. So now i want that if my current record count is greater than 10 then my jpages pagination show on page else not. How it is possible???
Thanks in advance.

-------------------- UpDATe ----------------
Thank you jai . following code worked..

```
$(function () {
               $("div.holder").jPages({
                   containerID: "movies",
                   previous: "←",
                   next: "→",
                   perPage: 10,
                   delay: 50,

                   callback: function (pages, items) {
                       if (items.count > 10) {
                           $("div.holder").show();
//                           $("#legend1").html("Page " + pages.current + " of " + pages.count);
//                           $("#legend2").html(items.range.start + " - " + items.range.end + " of " + items.count);
                       } else {
                           $("div.holder").hide();
                       }

                   }

               });
           });
```

Comment: Which plugin you are using(name?)?? There should be minPages ,something parameter given for the Plugin .So name?

Comment: @ Pratik Joshi hi See my question i give hyperlink on 'here' which shows the plugin.

Comment: From this link ,I dont come to know PLugin name,You tell Name of plugin you are using

Comment: plugin name is Jpages.

Comment: current record count is 6 MEANS ? Do you have total ITEMS that can span over 10 pages,OR Do you have 6 Items on one page?

Comment: Actually if my total record is less than 10 then i want to hide my pagination bar .

Comment: Per page how many items are you showing?

Comment: i want to show 10 items per page but if items are less than 10 then my pagination div should  be hide..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a callback to your `jPages` initializer:

```
callback : function( pages, items ){
    if(items.count > 10){
        $("#legend1").html("Page " + pages.current + " of " + pages.count);
        $("#legend2").html(items.range.start + " - " + items.range.end + " of " + items.count);
    }else{
        $("#legend1, #legend2").html('');
    }

  }
```

Comment: @social glad this helped you, but try to readout the documentation.